# How to do Cocoapods Installation?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I want to do Cocoapods Installation, but I have no any idea how to do it ?

Which version I have to download according to Xcode version ? 
Which setup setting I have to do ?

And finally how to do pod installation

like, **Add pod 'Parse' to your podfile and run pod install.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. open Terminal and type the following command:

> sudo gem update --system

2. Next, you need to install CocoaPods. Type this command in Terminal to do so:

> sudo gem install cocoapods

3. Then, enter this command in Terminal to complete the setup of CocoaPods:

> pod setup

4. Terminal and navigate to the directory containing your ShowTracker
   project by using the cd command:

> cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/yourproject

5. Next enter this command:

> pod init

6. Type this command to open Podfile using Xcode for editing:

> open -a Xcode Podfile

The default Podfile should look like this:

> ## Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
>
> ## platform :ios, "6.0"   target "ShowTracker" do   end

7. Replace # platform :ios, "6.0" with the following:(or whatever your base is)

> platform :ios, "7.0"

8. Finaly Add pod 'Parse' to your podfile and run.

> pod install

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2) for the step by step guide.

Answer (score 2):

1) Open terminal

2) $ **sudo gem install cocoapods** (gem will get installed in Ruby inside System library)

3)**pod setup**

4) create a xcode project

5) cd "$ path to your project root directory"

6) **pod init**

7) **open -a Xcode Podfile**

(podfile will get open in text mode. Initially it will be empty put  the follwing line of  code.)

8) pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'

(It’s finally time to add your dependencies using CocoaPods. Copy and paste the following into your pod file, right after target "AFNetworkingProject" do:)

9) **pod install**

Comment: Working Perfect

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal and execute following commands one by one:-

1. sudo gem install cocoapods
2. cd ~/PathOfXcodeProject
3. pod init

Go to finder and open your project's location. You will see there a pod file. Open that pod file and write

1. pod 'Parse'

Go to terminal and execute following command:

1. pod install

**Close the terminal, go to finder and open your project's location. Open .workspace file (not xcode project file).**